# Download Image From WebServer (cPanel/VPS) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, cpanel

I'm trying to make a function to download images from a server and use them in a picturebox and if needed save it locally. Right now I'm using:

```
Public Function WebImgDownload(ByVal Url As String, Optional ByVal saveFile As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal location As String = "C:\") As Image

        Dim client As New WebClient With {
        .Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")}
        Dim bytes() As Byte = client.DownloadData(Url)
        Dim stream As New IO.MemoryStream(bytes)

        If saveFile Then My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(location, bytes, False)

        Return New Bitmap(stream)

    End Function
```

Now this all works fine when I use the function like:

```
PictureBox1.Image = WebImgDownload("myurl")
```

But it only works when I provide world permissions to the folder on cPanel. If I only provide user permission to the folder so it will require authentication and use my credentials it responds with a 404 error message.

I'm using the user and password I login to the server but it just throws the error:

> System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.'

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found my error. I was trying to authenticate by just using the normal address when I needed to use the ftp address for the file. In my case I was using:

> https://myserver/folder/file.jpg

Now instead I used the ftp address like this:

> ftp://myserver/public_html/folder/file.jpg

That way it authenticates correctly and points to the file correctly too because not using the public_html in the address was pointing it to the wrong folder.

For some reason when you dont need to authenticate with the server you can just use the normal address when the file is public.